# How to install or upgrade to Helm Chart through Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am trying to install or upgrade Helm Chart through Azure Devops pipeline, but the pipeline getting failed with the following error.

```
    WARNING: Merged "akscluster-admin" as current context in 
    /home/AzDevOps/.kube/config
    /agent/_work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1685671456745.sh: line 5: helm list -n 
     devns - q | grep "splunk": command not found
    Splunk is already installed. Performing splunk upgrade
    Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "splunk" has no deployed release
```

Below is  the pipeline task:

```
    check_splunk= 'helm list -n devns - q | grep "splunk"'
    if [ -n "check_splunk" ]; then
        echo " Splunk is already installed. Performing splunk upgrade"

        helm -n devns upgrade splunk --values ./values.yaml 
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/splunk 

    else 
        echo "splunk is not installed, performing splunk installation"
    
        helm dependency update $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/splunk            
        helm -n devns install splunk --values ./values.yaml 
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/splunk
    fi
```

Also I have a "helm install" task on the same pipeline, but it's still failing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Locally is it working? can you share your full yaml pipeline?